# Memory management of primitive C types in objective c

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, primitive-types

If I alloc an object in my program, then I need to release it. If I create an int, then do I need to call free(myint) or will the variable be destroyed automatically at the end of my function? Also, if I add int, long, or bool properties to my objects, then do I need to handle then in dealloc or will they also be destroyed when the function I am using is completed?

Answer (score 4):

> If I create an int, then do I need to call free(myint) or will the variable be destroyed automatically at the end of my function?

It depends on how you do it: automatic variables of primitive types are deallocated when they do out of scope:

```
if (a == b) {
    int sum = 0;
    sum = a + b;
    NSLog(@"%d", sum);
}
```

If you allocate your primitive using `malloc` or `calloc`, you must use `free` at the end (I don't know why you'd want to use primitives like this, though):

```
if (a == b) {
    int *sumPtr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *sumPtr = a + b;
    NSLog(@"%d", *sumPtr);
    free(sumPtr);
}
```

Same rules are followed when you add primitive fields to your objects: if you use `malloc` in the `init`, then you must use `free` in `dealloc`. Otherwise, the value is allocated "in line" with the rest of your object, and do not need separate deallocation.

Answer (score 3):

As a superset of C, rules for automatic stack variables are the same.  So, defining `int x;` in a function means you don't have to do anything to clean it up because it is on the stack.  A heap allocation such as `int *x = malloc(...);` needs a `free(x);` at some point to clean up.  If these steps occur inside an object (e.g. in `init`) then it's the same idea; an `int` field can be left alone but an allocation needs to be balanced by a deallocation in the `dealloc` method of the class.

Answer (score 0):

the basic key point of the memory management (without any deeper details), you must `release` every objects you've created as `new`, `alloc` or `copy`; or after you've increased the `retain` counter for the current object.

in every other case you don't need to worry about calling the `release` method and you should not do it, it would take high risk of the crash.

*(this was just the rough basics of the memory management without ARC)*

you don't need to worry about the primitives except if you allocated the memory for them before with an `alloc(...);` or `malloc(...);`; in that case you must `free(...);` the allocated memory after you finished to use them.